# Proof that there aren't functions that satisfy $f(x)\cdot g(y)=x+y$, for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, functions

I have been presented with the following problem, and I'm only starting with proofs. **Any help, not necessarily the complete answer, is welcomed! I'm striving to really learn.**

Prove that there aren't any functions $\;f,g\;$, with domain and codomain $\mathbb{R}$, that satisfy the following:

$f(x)\cdot g(y)=x+y\;,\;$ for every $\;x,y\in\mathbb{R}\;.$

I'm really at a loss here. While it seems a bit intuitive for me, I can't seem to come up with any ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for math formatting, not just Markdown italics.

Comment: Excuse the title, which is a bit misleading, as the problem asks for proof that there aren't any functions that satisfy what is presented.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, Nate! I will do that.

Comment: Is it really $f(x)g(x)$, or should it be $f(x)g(y)$?

Comment: It is as you said. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: In any functional equation such as this, the first thing you check is what if $f(0)=g(0)=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(0)\cdot g(0) = 0+0=0$, therefore we can assume $f(0)=0$.
We get the contradiction $0 = 0\cdot g(1)= f(0)\cdot g(1) = 0+1=1\;.$

Comment: Thanks Vitor, but isn't that just a counterexample? Or does this apply for any possible value and function?

Comment: If such functions existed, the argument above leads us to a contradiction. Not just a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Very grateful.

Comment: @EnriqueMourey, notice in your question that you state for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, so if we find ONE counter example is enough to show that this is false. By contradiction is the perfect way to go about this.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the comment. I've updated the title question as it was misleading about the actual problem. As I understand it, only one counter example wouldn't be enough. Am I right?

Comment: @EnriqueMourey What do you mean by "counterexample"? If you mean "one pair of functions that don't work", then yes, that of course would not work. That is not what this is, though (although there is a slight subtlety: the "therefore we can assume $f(0) = 0$" part is using the symmetry between $f$ and $g$. If you don't see that, you could instead conclude from the first equation that one of $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ must be $0$, and then derive a contradiction from both (by identical proofs, hence the use of symmetry to cut out the duplicate)).

Comment: "isn't that just a counterexample" There's nothing "just" about a counterexample.  That's like saying "Isn't that just Armageddon?"

Comment: Didn't meant it like it wasn't useful, just was confused about it being a very specific and not a general answer. Thank you for the help everyone.

Comment: @user3482749 Thank you, that's exactly what I meant, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Throw rocks at it.  Look for simple values.

$f(0)g(0) = 0 + 0 = 0$  So one of $f(0),g(0)$ are $0$.

$f(0)g(1) = f(1)g(0) = 0 + 1 = 1$ so neither of $f(0),g(0)$ are $0$.

Okay... show's over.  let's go home.

Comment: Thank you very much!